# NSXMLParser delegates Handling Attributes

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, nsxmlparser

I am currently trying to get my parser delegates to work with a custom `NSObject` I have created for the attributes of the xml I am receiving..

This is the XML that is being read in to my parser delegates

```
<Rows>
<Row SKATERID="706" MANUFACTURER="GAZ" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="F"/>
<Row SKATERID="318" MANUFACTURER="MAN" ISFACT="F" ISSKATE="T"/>
//...
</Rows>
```

This is what I have for my `-parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"]) {

        manufactureNSObject = [[ManufactureNSObject alloc] init];

        manufactureNSObject.ISFACT = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ISFACT"];
         manufactureNSObject.ISSKATE = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ISSKATE"];
         manufactureNSObject.MANUFACTURER = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
         manufactureNSObject.SKATERID = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"SKATERID"];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", manufactureNSObject.ISFACT, manufactureNSObject.ISSKATE, manufactureNSObject.MANUFACTURER, manufactureNSObject.SKATERID);
    }    
}
```

My `NSLog` prints out all of the correct values fine, the next part that I am stuck on is the 
`- parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` method, nothing apart from the `didEndElement` is coming through correctly... this is what I have for that method.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"%@", elementName);
    NSLog(@"%@", namespaceURI);
    NSLog(@"%@", qName);
}
```

This is what my output looks like from the `NSLog`s.

```
2011-10-13 10:04:16.529 Code[52605:207] F F GAZ 76
2011-10-13 10:04:16.531 Code[52605:207] Row
2011-10-13 10:04:16.535 Code[52605:207] (null)
2011-10-13 10:04:16.537 Code[52605:207] (null)
2011-10-13 10:04:16.537 Code[52605:207] F T MAN 38
2011-10-13 10:04:16.538 Code[52605:207] Row
2011-10-13 10:04:16.539 Code[52605:207] (null)
2011-10-13 10:04:16.540 Code[52605:207] (null)
```

I specifically would like help with trying to complete the second method and get this all working correctly.

All the help so far has been greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone checks this page out in the future I have found out how to do this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"MANUFACTURER",cell.textLabel.text];
            NSArray *filterArray = [myDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
            [[self delegate] setManufactureSearchFields:filterArray withIndexPath:indexPath]; //This is where I pass the value back to the mainview
```

predicate are your friend.. and they are also good at isolating the values you want from a dictionary...

BOOM!

Answer (score 3):

For the type of xml file you are parsing, the

```
parser:foundCharacters:
```

is never called. This delegate method is called in such cases:

```
<mytag>this is the tag content</mytag>
```

while in your case only attributes are present and no tag content, that is:

```
<mytag attr1="value1" attr2="value2"></mytag>
```

As far as the other method:

```
parser:didEndElement:
```

its implementation is up to you. E.g. if you store an element inside a temporary variable then this method is useful to copy this variable inside another data structure.

Comment: yes, I am going to put the variables into their proper variables that represent their particular data types.. what method should I use for attributes?

Comment: it's the one you're already using: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict --> attributes are stored in the attributeDict

Comment: ah yea, I have been able to NSLog attributeDict.. I am just not sure how to get the values into my own variables.

Comment: I just dont know how to read the different elements inside xml Row.. its starting to get me really down.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `NSMutableString` that you can pass the string from `parser:foundCharacters` into. From there, implement a similar structure as you did in `parser:didStartElement:` only this time, you'll use that `NSMutableString` and pass its value into the object that is represented by the element being closed.

Comment: I have updated the second method, but its not even getting called when i debug it.. im not sure why.

Comment: What does your XML look like? Did you also implement `parser:parseErrorOccurred`?

Comment: I have updated my question with XML, and no I have not got parser:parseErrorOccurred implemented..