# iOS: NSXMLParser - A lot of attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, attributes, nsxmlparser

I know there are a lot of answers here and on google but i am stuck since 3 days figuring out how to handle my problem. I hope someone can give me a good advice.

All the content in my XML are attribute. They are parse into `attributeDict`. Now i am trying to handle the attributes with `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement....` and display them later in a TableView.

I have put the attributes into `NSMutableArray` and want to display the device name and his channels and the value of his datapoint. Later i would like to change the value of the daterpoint with a button. But i am not sure if this is the best way for what i am trying. I found this post with `NSPredicate`. Could this be the right way? Thanks a lot in advance!

[NSXMLParser delegates Handling Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734269/nsxmlparser-delegates-handling-attributes)

This is my code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement....

 if(![elementName isEqual:@"device"])
        return;
    Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    [Name addObject:name];

    if(![elementName isEqual:@"device"])
        return;
    Namedatapoint = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString * datapoint = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ise_id"];
    [Namedatapoint addObject:datapoint];

...
```

and this a part of my xml:

```
<stateList>
<device name="Fußbodenheizung" ise_id="1418" unreach="false" sticky_unreach="false" config_pending="false">

<channel name="HM-LC-Sw4-DR MEQ0213526:1" ise_id="1443" visible="true" operate="true">
<datapoint name="BidCos-RF.MEQ0213526:1.STATE" type="STATE" ise_id="1447" value="false" valuetype="2" valueunit="" timestamp="1454260698" operations="7"/>
</channel>
<channel name="HM-LC-Sw4-DR MEQ0213526:2" ise_id="1449" visible="true" operate="true">
<datapoint name="BidCos-RF.MEQ0213526:2.STATE" type="STATE" ise_id="1453" value="false" valuetype="2" valueunit="" timestamp="1454260785" operations="7"/>
</channel>
<channel name="HM-LC-Sw4-DR MEQ0213526:3" ise_id="1455" visible="true" operate="true">
<datapoint name="BidCos-RF.MEQ0213526:3.STATE" type="STATE" ise_id="1459" value="false" valuetype="2" valueunit="" timestamp="1454260786" operations="7"/>
</channel>
<channel name="HM-LC-Sw4-DR MEQ0213526:4" ise_id="1461" visible="true" operate="true">
<datapoint name="BidCos-RF.MEQ0213526:4.STATE" type="STATE" ise_id="1465" value="false" valuetype="2" valueunit="" timestamp="1454260786" operations="7"/>
</channel>
</device>
<device name="HM-CC-RT-DN MEQ0807085" .......
```

Comment: Use RaptureXML instead and thank me later - https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Name` and `Namedatapoint` are static, you should not `alloc init` them in `parser:didStartElement`. Doing so will erase previous data each time a new `device` is found.

If you wan't to keep allocation in `parser:didStartElement` do it lazily:

```
...
if (!Name) {
  Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
...
```